# "PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES" error with pip

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I'm trying to install packages using pip. In this case for OpenCV. However, I'm unable to install anything. I'm using python 3.5.3 en pip 18.0 (installed using get-pip.py).

Whatever I try, the command 'pip install package-name' generates the following error:

> THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
>       opencv-contrib-python-headless from https://www.piwheels.org/simple/opencv-contrib-python-headless/opencv_contrib_python_headless-3.4.3.18-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv6l.whl#sha256=ff894c0cc7c98b05b7b260a1dc462e7ad0a4220b042072fc0134a2b7a92bc4a5:
>           Expected sha256 ff894c0cc7c98b05b7b260a1dc462e7ad0a4220b042072fc0134a2b7a92bc4a5
>                Got        4119d8c56d19ef044c1faca317dd10f2bb3b50cbee77426a22feca9b641c5637

Things I've tried:

- using '--no-cache-dir' as suggested by another using having the same question.
- reinstalling python/pip or trying other versions of python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem that the https://pywheels.org/ maintainers need to fix.

https://www.piwheels.org/simple/opencv-contrib-python-headless/
 contains a link to [`opencv_contrib_python_headless-3.4.3.18-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv6l.whl`](https://www.piwheels.org/simple/opencv-contrib-python-headless/opencv_contrib_python_headless-3.4.3.18-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv6l.whl#sha256=ff894c0cc7c98b05b7b260a1dc462e7ad0a4220b042072fc0134a2b7a92bc4a5) with a SHA256 of `ff894c0cc7c98b05b7b260a1dc462e7ad0a4220b042072fc0134a2b7a92bc4a5` embedded in the URL.

However, downloading the file, its *actual* SHA256 is `4119d8c56d19ef044c1faca317dd10f2bb3b50cbee77426a22feca9b641c5637` (I get this myself, so it's not an attacker monkeying-in-the-middle with your network connection only to substitute malicious packages).

**This could mean that malicious tampering has gone on** (presumably by someone who's directly compromised PyWheels infrastructure), if an attacker has injected malware into the packages but not updated the checksums. The safe thing to do is to contact the site owners and ask that they investigate the issue.

Comment: I created an issue and the maintainers confirmed the problem was on their side. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused? What exactly do I have to do? I have the exact same error message instead with a different Expected Sha256 and Got. Sha256: `db3106b7ca86999a7bd1f2fcc93e49314e5e6e451356774e421a69428df5020b` and Got: `7aba82298c4332d97cec009d9e45ce79a52c29f0bf885ee264c35f9af06d7e2c`. I really need to fix this package I'm installing >.< Also, I'm using Windows

Comment: @Tigerrrrr, communicate with the author of the package. The goal of these checks is to prevent someone from tampering with a 3rd-party library (f/e, inserting a cryptominer or malware payload). If you just defeat the check, then you're (potentially) forcing installation of a malicious payload, so don't do that -- instead, communicate with the library's author; or, if you can get the source via another means (a PGP-signed git commit, f/e), do that instead.

Comment: Oh, well the I guess the package I was installing isn't really a known package, like 1 other install. So, I should probably not go carry on installing. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesDuffy | Oh, I probably shouldn't mentioned this earlier, it's a package on github, maybe you can read the python and see anything unusual? `https://github.com/GiantTreeLP/nimses-adimate`

Comment: So, what would actually be more appropriate is to download the code from PyPi, check out the tag for the same release from git, and then compare the two to see if they match. If they *do* match, determine if the git commits in that release are signed by someone you trust to be the legit author. If the code matches and the commits are signed, then it's pretty safe that you can go ahead and install it.

Comment: There is another scenario, where something like enterprise TLS inspection is causing the hash to change by delivering a slightly different version of the file. This is known to happen with Sophos, specifically, though other vendors are not immune.