# Can there be an object (e.g. a list) instead of a test expression in python 'elif'?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def lines(file): # a text file 
    for line in file:yield line
    yield "\n"
def blocks(file):
    block=[]
    for line in lines(file):
        if not line.isspace():
            block.append(line)
        elif block:  #a list in elif test expression
            yield ''.join(block).strip()
```

Comment: Yes, there can. The code you've shared demonstrates it.

Comment: Yes you can. Non-empty `list` objects evaluate to Truthy. Empty `list` objects will evaluate to Falsey.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: anything that can be passed to `bool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the list isn't empty then yes you can use a list to be evaluated as a `True` bool in and if/elif/else statement. Empty lists will be `False`, lists with at least 1 item will be `True`

You can always just try your own code out to see for yourself!

Comment: What do you mean "so long as the list isn't None"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My bad, meant empty

Comment: See the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions which *"...have already been asked and answered many times before"*.

Comment: Why couldn't you use an empty list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've interpreted OP's question as asking if the the object will be evaluated as `True` but technically an empty list is a valid argument too, yes. Just it'll be false. It depends how you interpret the questions I guess.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yup, but it was a simple answer so I figured it'd be easier for OP to just get the answer here as well. If it was a more involved answer I'd have left it. I'm also not the only user that answered it (see below).

Comment: *nod* -- the others should know better too. (BTW, an option to distinguish rep farming from trying to provide a useful summary to a bad answer is use of the "Community Wiki" option when posting an answer to something you know/believe isn't a valid question).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not familiar with the Community Wiki option, mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: Selecting Community Wiki "disowns" a post -- grants permission for others to edit it at-will, showing ownership as a percentage of content contributed rather than a single name, and disclaims any rep gain from its upvotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407041/packages-do-not-match-the-hashes-error-with-pip/52407348#52407348 for an example of a CW post with my name on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid. Empty lists yield `False`, otherwise the expression yields `True`.

If you want more clarity, you can also use a more verbose form:

```
if ...
    ...
elif len(block) > 0:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because any object can be tested for truth value in Python as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
> condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.
>
> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
> either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method
> that returns zero, when called with the object. [1] Here are most of
> the built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: None and False.
> - zero of any numeric type: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
> - empty sequences and collections: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)
>
> Operations and built-in
> functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for
> false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important
> exception: the Boolean operations or and and always return one of
> their operands.)