# Clean Docker pip install results in ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip

My Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# System setup
ENV USER app
ENV APP_DIR /home/app

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ${USER}

# System dependencies
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential \
  libffi-dev \
  libpq-dev

# Update pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools --user --no-cache-dir
RUN pip3 install wheel --user --no-cache-dir

WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

# App dependencies
COPY setup.py ${APP_DIR}/
RUN pip3 install --extra-index-url {url} -e ${APP_DIR}/.[test] --user
```

with the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  application-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ~/.config/appsecrets/secrets.yaml:/var/lib/appsecrets/app.yaml:ro
    environment:
      APP_LOG_LEVEL: INFO
```

and with the following `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="context_manager",
    install_requires=[
        "gunicorn[gevent]==20.0.4",
        "nltk==3.4.5",
        "psycopg2==2.7.3.2",
        "pyyaml==5.1.2",
        "pyparsing==2.4.6",
        "sentry-sdk==0.14.0",
        "tldextract==2.2.2",
    ],
    extras_require={"test": ["pytest", "pytest-cov", "mock"]},
)
```

This results in the following error

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.

    nltk==3.4.5 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/1d/d925cfb4f324ede997f6d47bea4d9babba51b49e87a767c170b77005889d/nltk-3.4.5.zip#sha256=bed45551259aa2101381bbdd5df37d44ca2669c5c3dad72439fa459b29137d94 (from context-manager==0.0.0):
        Expected sha256 bed45551259aa2101381bbdd5df37d44ca2669c5c3dad72439fa459b29137d94
             Got        ce4ae7079a05635aa5a2e7f464593524d4b047982c06c012c53d1658175043b6

    gevent>=0.13; extra == "gevent" from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/55/85c758c389a3c84f999b445e423b6b148227f03104fa7957e84179d9a97b/gevent-20.5.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=31dc5d4ab8172cc00c4ff17cb18edee633babd961f64bf54214244d769bc3a74 (from gunicorn[gevent]==20.0.4->context-manager==0.0.0):
        Expected sha256 31dc5d4ab8172cc00c4ff17cb18edee633babd961f64bf54214244d769bc3a74
             Got        02444a3dbde12419a14ad40ac2dff92466f5fbfb1c566c94b44ce01497bdbdb2

    urllib3>=1.10.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/e5/df302e8017440f111c11cc41a6b432838672f5a70aa29227bf58149dc72f/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=88206b0eb87e6d677d424843ac5209e3fb9d0190d0ee169599165ec25e9d9115 (from sentry-sdk==0.14.0->context-manager==0.0.0):
        Expected sha256 88206b0eb87e6d677d424843ac5209e3fb9d0190d0ee169599165ec25e9d9115
             Got        d00015c954667a679b32f8d1892cd6264f725e44df87e1ca775678c409f1faef
```

This has just recently started, and is not affecting anyone else trying to build the same image.

I have tried with and without `--user` and `--no-cache-dir` on all the pip3 install commands with no luck. The docker container is running without any cached steps. I am using Docker version 19.03.1 on Windows (Home).

Any ideas on what could be the cause of this?

Comment: It looks as though those URLs might not be getting downloaded correctly? You could debug by putting a `wget` and `sha256sum` further up to see if it affects everything or only pip. That first URL should be returning a file hashing to `bed455...` and it did when I just tried it locally.

Comment: getting the correct sha on the wget, but still getting the has mismatch as part of the pip install

Comment: sorry for the obvious question but : how does your docker command (the docker run command) looks like ? do you add any flags on it, any port mapping or any volumes ?

Comment: @yAzou `docker-compose --file docker-compose.local.yaml down --remove-orphans || true`

where my docker-compose has

```
build:

      context: .

      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: @PhillipGodzin can you include your docker-compose in the question ?

Comment: @MickaelB. updated with the docker-compose

Comment: Where does that _requirements file_ comes from? What is the content? What is the full log that leads to that error message?

Comment: @sinoroc what do you mean where does the requirements file come from? The requirements are defined in the setup.py. The rest of the log is just the rest of the docker steps and the successful part of the pip install

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52407348/10020419

Comment: @theshadog yes, in this case it is a local-only issue that is not reproducible, implying it is not something wrong with the package itself.

Comment: Just in case, have you tried to build that Dockerfile with `--no-cache` option, and add before last pip install `rm -rf ~/.cache/pip` It must be something related to cache. Also, you could try to change user (USER USER) in that Dockerfile since you are using `--user` flag.

Comment: When you run 'docker-compose up' have you tried adding --force-recreate? Worth a try ...

Comment: @Niklas yes have tried with both options, including deleting all images to make sure nothing is being cached

Comment: Try adding a `--no-use-pep517` to all your `pip3` commands and see if it helps. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6158

Comment: On the last line of  `Dockerfile`, when installing app dependencies, try adding `--no-cache-dir` option to the pip3 command.

Comment: I have tried your sample and seams that adding ```ENV url 'https://pypi.org/simple'``` and ``RUN pip3 install --extra-index-url $url -e ${APP_DIR}/.[test] --user`` on linux ubuntu version, the application builds without any problem.

Comment: @MUNGAINJOROGE were you able to reproduce the issue without that? I have had trouble getting others to reproduce

Comment: Nop, the first issue I faced was with the URL so I picked the one from pypi. After this, the build was successful. Maybe it might be an issue with Docker version or Windows.

Answer (score 3):

This is very likely to be an issue with pip 20.1.0 which is released recently and made it into the `python:3.7-slim` images: https://github.com/docker-library/python/commit/b818e9441c088295165edf79a791503f1fe7f6f7

If you replace your `# Update pip` section with `pip install pip==20.0.2` these should go away.

Regarding why, I think this change might be responsible: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/609

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael-Rigoni suggests, try adding --no-cache-dir to the final pip3 command.

```
RUN pip3 install --extra-index-url {url} -e ${APP_DIR}/.[test] --user --no-cache-dir
```

That command could be finding cached hash values in a temp folder. For others experiencing this error, the most common workarounds other than adding `--no-cache-dir` seem to be:

1. Try using wget to download the library files before running pip
2. Try running the install processes without setuptools
3. Try running `python setup.py clean --all` and possibly `python setup.py develop`

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I had the exact same issue after updating Docker. My environment was completely broken and when I tried to start my services I would get the following error message:

> ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.

The sentence that eludes to an attacker had me thinking about my VPN settings. Once I disconnected from VPN, my error message went away and my environment was fixed.

I hope my solution works for you too.