# pip install failed, in ubuntu18 or in clean docker container because hash doesn't match

Tags: python, pip, wget

The problem is like following one.
In some machines, I can't install django with `pip`. (not only django, but also numpy and so on...)

```sh
$ pip install --no-cache-dir django
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
     |????????????????????????????????| 7.8 MB 5.6 MB/s
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    django from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/6f/9a4415cc4fe9228e26ea53cf2005961799b2abb8da0411e519fdb74754fa/Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=baf099db36ad31f970775d0be5587cc58a6256a6771a44eb795b554d45f211b8:
        Expected sha256 baf099db36ad31f970775d0be5587cc58a6256a6771a44eb795b554d45f211b8
             Got        7140cf41703d27896793ef3ca9f79323d12eac477f8cea29c79c76a7f17379f1
```

I checked the some articles in stackoverflow and noticed that there are many questions concerning this problem.
Learning from those articles, then I'm struggling.

By the way, in stackoverflow, I found the answer which says this problem is likely to be the issue of the `pip`.
Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61731528/8674852.

So I tried installing in the machine with old pip, then I have succeeded to install `django` with `pip`.
It is the `pip 20.3.3`.

### Succeeded

```sh
$ pip --version
pip 20.3.3 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

$ pip install django
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
     |????????????????????????????????| 7.8 MB 2.8 MB/s
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.2.10
  Using cached asgiref-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
     |????????????????????????????????| 510 kB 3.0 MB/s
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, pytz, asgiref, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.3.1 django-3.1.7 pytz-2021.1 sqlparse-0.4.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

### Failed

But the other machine with `pip 21.0.1` failed to install django.

```sh
$ pip --version
pip 21.0.1 from /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    django from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/6f/9a4415cc4fe9228e26ea53cf2005961799b2abb8da0411e519fdb74754fa/Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=baf099db36ad31f970775d0be5587cc58a6256a6771a44eb795b554d45f211b8:
        Expected sha256 baf099db36ad31f970775d0be5587cc58a6256a6771a44eb795b554d45f211b8
             Got        7c5af478cb5c9748d0477912637f98da101a0e7be763b61c71c053e0cc98fa08
```

But ...., In this machine, even if I downgraded `pip` into `20.0.2` or `20.3.3`, the result didn't changed, installing failed.

```sh
$ pip install pip==20.0.2
Collecting pip==20.0.2
  Downloading pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
     |????????????????????????????????| 1.4 MB 3.1 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.0.1
Successfully installed pip-20.0.2

$ pip install --no-cache-dir django
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
     |????????????????????????????????| 7.8 MB 6.4 MB/s
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    django from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/6f/9a4415cc4fe9228e26ea53cf2005961799b2abb8da0411e519fdb74754fa/Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=baf099db36ad31f970775d0be5587cc58a6256a6771a44eb795b554d45f211b8:
        Expected sha256 baf099db36ad31f970775d0be5587cc58a6256a6771a44eb795b554d45f211b8
             Got        ba57de6ac1d02039af8ce41e9af8663fd9fb6b62db55870b9b1e6eabe5c1ff73

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

## Environment

By the way, all of the above execution of commands was done in the same host PC.
But I tried `pip install django` in several different environments in the same host PC.

| pip | Guest OS | Virtual mechanism | Host OS | Specified version | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.3.3 | Ubuntu18 | virtualbox | windows10 | null | success |
| 20.3.3 | Ubuntu18 | virtualbox | same with above | 3.1.7 | success |
| 21.0.1 | Ubuntu20 | WSL2 | same with above | null | success |
| 21.0.1 | Ubuntu20 | WSL2 | same with above | 3.1.7 | success |
| 20.0.2 | CentOS7 | virtualbox | same with above | null | fail |
| 20.0.2 | CentOS7 | virtualbox | same with above | 3.1.7 | fail |
| 20.3.3 | CentOS7 | virtualbox | same with above | null | fail |
| 20.3.3 | CentOS7 | virtualbox | same with above | 3.1.7 | fail |
| 21.0.1 | CentOS7 | virtualbox | same with above | null | fail |
| 21.0.1 | Ubuntu18 (different from above) | virtualbox | same with above | null | fail |
| 21.0.1 | Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) | docker | ubuntu18 on windows10 | null | fail |
| 21.0.1 | Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) | docker | ubuntu18 on windows10 | 3.1.7 | fail |

* To specify version I executed `$ pip install django==3.1.7` and `pip install --no-cache-dir django==3.1.7`

## Question

Why these problem occurs ?
Is the cause of this problem the network configuration ?
Is there anything I could do for finding the solution ?

---

### Memo

One committer for the `pip` said

> it sounds like a network configuration problem on your production server

Please refer to [pypa/pip : package installation issue on the server-THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE #8510](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8510#issuecomment-809723718)

But no one knows what kind of network configuration effects against the hash.
Could you tell me how I can investigate the cause network configuration?

---

There is also other answer saying it is the problem of https://pywheels.org/.
Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52407348/8674852.

But...., at least, though it is not everytime, I succeeded to execute `pip install django`.
So, I'm not sure but I think https://pywheels.org/ isn't the cause of this problem at now.

---

#### About other module

pip can't install not only django, but also numpy in above failed environment.

This is the sample of the result executed in docker container.

```sh
# in this container, I executed `pip install numpy --no-cache-dir`
web_1  | Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (21.0.1)
web_1  | Collecting numpy
web_1  |   Downloading numpy-1.20.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.4 MB)
web_1  | ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
web_1  |     numpy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/f6/60e7d3a1da53a9979f37931d3cc619211accb339df06af8b387889b8d6ba/numpy-1.20.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=edb1f041a9146dcf02cd7df7187db46ab524b9af2515f392f337c7cbbf5b52cd:
web_1  |         Expected sha256 edb1f041a9146dcf02cd7df7187db46ab524b9af2515f392f337c7cbbf5b52cd
web_1  |              Got        ea51c3b37824f3efff5ad03076fdeb6d802e153664ec73599054a006262105a5
```

Besides, I couldn't even downgrade pip in docker container which failed to install django 3.1.7.

Comment: What's in your `requirements.txt` file? Which version of Django does this hash correspond to? You need to specify the Django version as well as the hash; each version will have a different hash.

Comment: This is an experiment to find out the cause of `ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE.`.

I hadn't used requirements.txt and specified the version of django at all in this experiment.

Let me try `pip install` with specifying the version of django. Wait a minute, please.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-precise/issues/79#issuecomment-502495344?

Comment: @tripleee I run pip install specifying the version of django, but the result didn't change...(I added the result to above, please see it) Perhaps, it seems that it doesn't matter if the version is specified or not.

Comment: @TrakeVital Thank you for your suggestion. You mean `pip install --no-cache-dir {module_name}`, right? If so, I have already tried it.

Comment: Because I was told that the cause seems to be some network configuration, I tried to do same thing using other network than the one I ordinary use.
But the result was more worse.
I got `ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE.` not only after I ran pip install in the docker, but also after I ran pip install in the Ubuntu18 in which I had succeeded it previously.

So, network may affect the result. But these information doesn't help us to resolve this problem. What shuold I do to find out more detailed cause?